# Dispatcher.DisableProcessing - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dispatcher

I am investigating Dispatcher.DisableProcessing() as a means to pause and resume UI rendering and I am attempting to use it without the using(){} statement.

It throws the InvalidOperationException - Dispatcher processing has been suspended but messages are still being processed.

Question:
Why this exception is thrown?
Is there any way I could use it outside of using(){} statement?

Thanks in advance!

-Edited to include testing code-

Workflow:

That exception still hits after successfully running through OnPauseButtonClick code.

```
public class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private DispatcherProcessingDisabled x;

    public void OnPauseButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        x = Dispatcher.DisableProcessing();
    }

    public void OnTestButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 1000);
    }

    public void TimerCallback(object o)
    {
        //all codes were commented out
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found where the Dispatcher throws the exception.

```
    [UIPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand,Unrestricted=true)]
    [SecurityCritical]
    public static void PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
    {
        if(frame == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("frame");
        }

        Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        if(dispatcher._hasShutdownFinished) // Dispatcher thread - no lock needed for read
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.DispatcherHasShutdown));
        }

        if(frame.Dispatcher != dispatcher)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.MismatchedDispatchers));
        }
        //here
        if(dispatcher._disableProcessingCount > 0) 
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.DispatcherProcessingDisabled));
        }

        dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(frame);
    }
```

[Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,56ab2a82578dc8f8)

According to the stacktrace, this function is called by Application.RunInternal. The application pushed a work into the Dispatcher which couldn't do it because it was disabled. My guess would be that this work is the effect of push on the button and then the glowing effect when a Button is focused but I can't be sure.